# Restrict access to Azure static web app to Entra ID's with an emailadres with certain domainname?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-static-web-app, microsoft-entra-id

I want to give people access to my Azure static web app by logging in with their Microsoft Entra ID. But someone should only have access to the site when their emailadress have a certain domainname.

For example, I only accept the domainname testemail.com.

Jonny@othermail.com should not me able to log in, while bob@testemail.com should be able to login and see the website.

Comment: Is your application single-tenant or multi-tenant?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question fully. Is there multiple apps authenticating with B2C and a certain one must be restricted by certain email domains, or do all of your apps require signing up with certain domains?

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!